# Unable to deploy image into GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry, gcloud-deploy

I have created a docker image locally and pushed it to GCP container registry using gcloud sdk. The image is successfully pushed to container registry.

Now, I am trying to manually deploy this image from the container registry on to the existing private GKE cluster from the GCP UI by selecting Deploy to GKE option.
After deploying, I am getting an error saying "container has runasNonRoot and the image will run as root (pod:"appname-XXXXX_default(XXXXXX-XXXX....)", container:appName-1): CreateContainerConfigError "
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a pod security policy setup to avoid running containers as root. This is a good security policy because of the risk of breakout into other applications or nodes within the cluster.

You might want to read up on the [Kubernetes security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) and potentially rebuild your container.

With my clusters I would often have to consume public images that use root, in this case I would consume the previous image as a base, create a new (non-root) user and new group to take ownership of any tools that are needed in the image.

Changing the default user in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu


RUN groupadd --gid 15555 notroot \ 
    && useradd --uid 15555 --gid 15555 -ms /bin/false notroot\
    && chown -R notroot:notroot /home/notroot

USER notroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
CMD ["whoami && id"]
```

[Here's a better explanation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/18/11-ways-not-to-get-hacked/#8-run-containers-as-a-non-root-user) of why you should avoid root in Docker images.